# Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4

Tags: android, android-support-library, retrofit, butterknife

After installing my app, it only runs the first time correctly and after that it crashes every time. All needed dependencies are included and up-to-date. I already tried to clean the project and rebuild it with different version of the libraries and on different devices.

Logcat:

```
02-20 04:45:50.830    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat21$SharedElementCallbackImpl; (58)
02-20 04:45:50.830    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat21$SharedElementCallbackImpl;' failed
02-20 04:45:51.160    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1; (1078)
02-20 04:45:51.160    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;' failed
02-20 04:45:51.180    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1078)
02-20 04:45:51.180    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed
02-20 04:45:51.990    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompatApi21$1; (185)
02-20 04:45:51.990    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompatApi21$1;' failed
02-20 04:45:52.120    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompatApi21$CallbackProxy; (186)
02-20 04:45:52.120    1052-1052/xxxW/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompatApi21$CallbackProxy;' failed
02-20 04:45:52.170    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompatApi21$CallbackProxy; (190)
02-20 04:45:52.170    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompatApi21$CallbackProxy;' failed
02-20 04:45:52.800    1052-1052/xxx I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompatApi21$1; interface 1124 'Landroid/view/View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;'
02-20 04:45:52.800    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompatApi21$1;' failed
02-20 04:45:53.540    1052-1052/xxx I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayoutCompatApi21$InsetsListener; interface 1124 'Landroid/view/View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;'
02-20 04:45:53.540    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayoutCompatApi21$InsetsListener;' failed
02-20 04:45:53.910    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lbutterknife/internal/ButterKnifeProcessor; (3572)
02-20 04:45:53.910    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lbutterknife/internal/ButterKnifeProcessor;' failed
02-20 04:46:01.440    1052-1052/xxx I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lretrofit/RxSupport$1; interface 4126 'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;'
02-20 04:46:01.440    1052-1052/xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lretrofit/RxSupport$1;' failed
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Go to Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Order and Export, see if it's checked the "android-support-v4.jar"

Comment: I'm using Android Studio and not Eclipse.

Comment: Are you sync the gradle?

Comment: A guy with the same problem solved it doing $ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar

Comment: The jar is in that directory. How exactly did he solved the problem?

Comment: Adding this path to the variable environtment on your pc

Comment: Doesn't work. Do you have an other hint?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multidexing in your app to get around Android's [65K method limit](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/building/multidex.html)?

I had a similar problem to this, and I figured out that I was running up against the [limitations of the multidex support library](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/building/multidex.html#limitations) - specifically the [`LinearAlloc`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78035) issue. There isn't really a good solution for that other than to try to rip out unused libs from your project, use [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/help/proguard.html), or set your `minSdkVersion` to 21.

Maybe this is not same issue that is causing your problem, but hopefully this helps anyone who ends up here.